# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

Error :

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MFBDCP.HotelList+geolocation]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

My Code :

```
HotelResponse myDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelResponse>(final);
```

Parent Class :

```
public class HotelResponse
{
   public List<hotels> hotels { get; set; } = new List<hotels>();
   public DateTime checkin { get; set; }
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class hotels
{
   public string hotel_code { get; set; }
   public List<geolocation> geolocation { get; set; }
}
```

Sub Child Class:

```
public class geolocation
{
   public string longitude { get; set; }
   public string latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Please let me know how to define nested lists

Comment: Show your JSON.

Comment: Please, follow C# naming conventions. Property names should start from capital letter.

Comment: Furthermore `hotels` should be the properties name, not the class´ name. That should be singular and PascalCase: `Hotel`.

Comment: Can you state in plain English what you are trying to accomplish here, what your inputs are and what is the behaviour you would expect. Just pasting code and stacktraces is not really clear

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a mistake in the input string, final. The error message indicates that one of the arrays (lists) is not formed correctly. Since you have nested lists, it could be either the inner or outer array that is not formed correctly.

What I would do is, create an actual HotelResponse object programatically, which contains the same property values as final. Then, use JsonConvert.SerializeObject() to see what the Json should look like. By comparing the results of JsonConvert.SerializeObject to final, you should be able to figure out what is wrong.